# How to pass state to OAuth when using the Google API Client Library for .NET?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google OAuth API Client Library for .NET
The code I'm using is based on: [Oauth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

The authorisation is working fine.

I'd like to pass a couple of parameters into the authorisation process. It seems the state querystring is used for this process, but I can't see how to achieve this with the C# client library.

Comment: what do you want to pass exactly.  I am not all that sure that you can pass anything else into the queries

Comment: 2 string values. On https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl it says "state - Provides any state that might be useful to your application upon receipt of the response." but I can't see how to set this with the Google client library.

Comment: what string values exactly?   The client library handles the authentication for you. To what purpose do you thing the authentication server would put your two strings to?

Comment: In my app I want the user to enter a couple of fields, then choose an option. If the option is Google I then ask the user to authorise with oauth. I'd like the field data after the authorisation. I could store them in a session, but I'd rather not. So to be clear the extra fields are for my app, not the authentication server.

Comment: I have a feeling state is read only in the library.   I sent a message to the lead developer on the project.   get back to you soon.

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/524