# Using Google OAuth2 API Client Library for .NET how to override the port?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I'm using the [Google API Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) and all works well on my local machine.
My testing environment is behind a load balancer. The way this is set up the site is viewed as https://, and the load balancer forwards port 443 to port 81. The user doesn't see the forward, they see https:// with no port number.

When the library creates the urls for redirection etc it's appending the port number to the urls. This means that after authorization it redirects to a url with :81 appended. Since the load balancer doesn't know about port 81 this fails.

Overriding GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and removing the :81 from the RedirectUri results in an Error:"redirect_uri_mismatch". I think this is probably due to the callback querystring containing state with the port 81 in.

I know from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179334/how-to-pass-state-to-oauth-when-using-the-google-api-client-library-for-net) that state is readonly in this library, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Easiest solution is to just add both redirect uri one for 443 and one for 81 in google developer console.  If that doesn't work create a client id for native instead of a web application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that didn't work, I still get the redirect_uri_mismatch error.

Comment: Was worth a shot.  Hang in there I have pinged the lead developer on the project he may have another idea.

Comment: I realised that the load balancer rule was a bit dumb... I simply made https 443 use port 80 on the server. I don't know why it was set up to use 81. Now all working fine.